# Error while installing less

Tags: node.js, less, npm

When i try to install less via this command:

```
npm install less .
```

I get an error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EROFS, symlink '../less/bin/lessc'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "less" "."
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/epi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path ../less/bin/lessc
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno 56
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/epi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm using debian wheezy and I've installed node from [sources](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#build-from-source).

Comment: What did `cat /var/www/epi/npm-debug.log` say? - EROFS usually means that you only can read from the filesystem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running the install again with the `--no-bin-link` flag.

```
npm install --no-bin-link less .
```

When you perform a normal install the structure looks like this:

```
.
└── node_modules
    ├── .bin
    │   └── lessc
    └── less
```

All the `--no-bin-link` flag does is remove the symlink:

```
node_modules/.bin/lessc --> node_modules/less/bin/lessc
```

The `lessc` executable can still be used:

```
.
└── node_modules
    └── less
        └── bin
            └── lessc
```

---

All the above thoughts came from your specific error:

```
Error: EROFS, symlink
```

But more generally the `EROFS` error just means  "Error: read only file system", so you may just need to change the permissions on your directory that you're running the install command in, or run it as root with `sudo`.

Comment: The --no-bin-link solution helped me with my virtualized installation. I'm working with a shared folder on the host computer, and had many troubles installing some packages.